# Complex Sql queries to to validate

Tags: mysql, oracle, teradata-sql-assistant

These are some of the complex sql queries asked to me in recent ETL testing interview:

What are the exact sql queries to validate:

1)wild characters check in my sql and oracle.

2)debit card and credit card numbers check in my sql and oracle.

3)email address validation in my sql and oracle.

4)SSN validation in my sql and oracle.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Weird - I would expect to handle all of these validations in application code.

Comment: Vague questions - perhaps the point was to push back on the interviewee.

Comment: @Strawberry  these are actually the sql questions asked to me in an interview was told to write the query which I found difficult. So, just needed help regarding it.

Comment: @P.Salmon  yes I think so.

Answer (score 2):

All the validation can be done using the REGEXP_LIKE function in MySQL and oracle. Check documentation for detail.

Comment: @ AbhiskekK could you please provide me the documentation link ? That would really be helpful!

Comment: MYSQL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html
ORACLE - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trigger that validate the things with regEx for validations

https://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/validating-data-using-a-trigger/

Comment: could you please provide me example? It would be really helpful.I am recently into IT and do not have good exposure.